# Do you prefer C# or Visual Basic .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What do you see as benefits for one over the other? As far as I know, it's just preference. I have way more experience with C# than I do with Visual Basic and was wondering if I should dabble in Visual Basic for certain types of projects?

Comment: Community wiki this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally prefer C#, I love the syntax and I feel really comfortable with the language.

Some say that [C# programmers are paid better](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/news/showTopic.aspx?ixTopic=503) than VB programmers, but I think you should try both languages and see on which you fell better.

- [Top 10 reasons C# is better than VB.NET](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=63)
- [Top 10 reasons VB.NET is better than C#](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=65)

Answer (score 6):

VB4 was my first language, with VB6 being the last time I touched it.  I have moved to c# and wouldnt consider going back. VB just feels too fat and fluffy for me (preference).

All the .NET languages compile to IL though...

Note: c# is "closer" to java...

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on doing any [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) you will need to know VB.  This one of few areas that I am aware of in which it truly matters which language you choose as SSIS only supports VB for any "integrated" code you write for it.

You are correct in saying that it is a preference as all .NET languages are compiled to IL.  So choose the one you are most comfortable with and don't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from a curly-braces background I find c# to be a lot easier to read and write. I find VB.Net to be too verbose and some of the syntax (I'm looking at you, arrays) makes my eyes water.

I also get frustrated by the background compilation in VB.Net, especially on large projects where it can make the IDE unresponsive.

The only advantage VB.Net has over C# in my opinion is optional parameters. These make certain interop tasks a lot easier but I think c# is due to get them in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET

In my opinion, C# was created only for marketing reasons to bring Java developers to .NET.

There are many more developer jobs in the job marketplace for C# over VB.  Visual Basic got a bad wrap from the get go because it was an interpreted language.  Back in the early days of computers, interpreted was bad and slow.

In the beginning, Microsoft built VB mostly for consultants to be able to quickly and effectively write internal software.

I cringe when I see C#, but these days, I write in JavaScript more than any other language and I love it.

VB's language keywords makes more sense to me over C#'s such as Imports vs Using.  With declarations, I  do not like having object type coming before the variable's name.  And it seems that C# has many hidden rules with parenthesis and what not that a developer must know just to even read C#.  Whereas VB is straight to the point and flows very nicely without crazy syntaxes.

Comment: VB is totally inferior comparing to C#. All the things you said against C# are good things of C#.

Comment: @gljivar actually there are things you can do in VB which you cannot do in C#. It's not totally inferior at all. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/10-reasons-why-visual-basic-is-better-than-c/